# Validating JavaScript origins

Tags: python, validation

I need to write a function in Python that makes sure the user entered a valid JavaScript origin. If I understand it correctly, the origin includes the scheme, hostname and port (port and scheme might be implicit, defaulting to 80 and http respectively), so would this be a correct way to validate it?

```
import urlparse

def validate_javascript_origin(origin):
    parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(origin)

    if parsed.scheme and parsed.scheme not in ["http", "https"]:
        raise ValueError("Only the http and https url schemes are supported.")

    if not parsed.netloc:
        raise ValueError("The origin must include a hostname.")

    if parsed.path or parsed.query or parsed.fragment:
        raise ValueError("The origin must not contain a path, query string or fragment.")
```

The origin will be used to pass as the preferredOrigin to [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

The main thing I'm worried about is that I'm not sure how credentials in the url (username:password@example.com) are handled.

Going to `http://username@frederikcreemers.be`, and getting `location.origin`in javascript returns `http://frederikcreemers.be`, so the origin doesn't include credentials. Would it be sufficient to add a condition like this to the function above:

```
if "@" in parsed.netloc:
    raise ValueError("The origin must not contain credentials.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First off, easy task, add a docstring to your function, `validate_javascript_origins`, and describe this function, and its arguments, preferably in detail.
2. Finally, if you're worried about input like `username@site.end`, you should add the check for the `@` character. If it isn't valid input, or the input is interpreted in the wrong way, you should most definitely add this check.